# c# regex get strings that have a specific sequence of letters and digits

Tags: c#, regex

I've searched around here but I haven't found a satisfying answer so I've decided to ask.
I need to search a collection of strings to find expressions like:

```
AB 12345
AC 12345
```

I've tried this regex

```
[A][BC][ ]\d{5}
```

But unfortunately in the strings there are also

```
#XXAB 1234567890123
GGAB 12345678901
AB 123456
SAB 123456789
```

And the above expression gets all these as valid.
I've found and tried

```
[A][BC][ ]\d{5}$
```

But this does not match anything.

So the question is, is there an expression to find the strings with 5 numbers followed by anything except more numbers?

From the answers I think I was really not clear in my exposition, the strings are in the middle of a larger string so I set some possible string that I must match:

```
MY DESCRIPTION WITH DATA XXXAB 12345BCD
```

and also

```
MY SECOND DESCRIPTION WITH DATA REF. AB 12345
```

and also

```
MY THIRD DESCRIPTION WITH DATA REFAB 12345
```

and also

```
AB 12345WITH A DESCRIPTION FOLLOWING
AB 12345 WITH A SPACE AND DESCRIPTION FOLLOWING
```

The strings are all uppercase in the database.

Comment: `[0-9]{5}(^[0-9])*$` - exactly 5 digits followed by anything but digits

Comment: Thanks for this string but using it with the ending $ I have no matches maybe its something of .Net? without the ending $ seemed to work but then I found a string in the form: XYAB 1234567 1234 as valid. It seems that this is really tricky. Thanks anyway

Comment: Well, in the string `XYAB 1234567 1234` you don't have "5 numbers followed by anything except more numbers": `1234` is just **4** digits, not **5** and `34567` is *followed* by `1234` so my regex, IMHO, does right. May be you want to put the condition  "5 numbers followed by anything except more numbers" in other words?

Comment: Yes what you say is correct, excluding the case you show would be good for my search but I have strings like XXAB 12345XY67  and strings like BLA BLA BLA AB 12345 BLA BLA BLA that are not considered correct either when the expression has the $ using the $ sign does not give any valid string, that is why I said maybe it is a .net problem with this kind of expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `?!` lookahead.

```
A[BC] \d{5}(?!\d)
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/oR7zJ6/2

Comment: Thank you, sorry for not explaining all correctly but my strings are in the middle of a larger string as I added to the request.

Comment: This works correctly and only the records with five numbers match. Thankyou very much to all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a `^` to indicate the beginning of the line:

```
^A[BC] \d{5}$
```

This will match any line starting by `A` followed by either `B` or `C`, then a space and 5 digits. Nothing else after it.

Note I am saying `A` instead of your `[A]`, since a character class is used whenever you have more than one possible character. `A` and `[A]` are equivalent, so just say `A` to simplify.

See it live in: https://regex101.com/r/mZ3mZ6/4 showing how it matches the examples you gave and does not the other ones.

Comment: Thanks, your answer made me notice that my question was not clear, the strings are in the middle of a larger string usually even if they can be at the beginning or the end of  but it is not always the case.

Comment: @Sabrina_cs then update giving cases that should match and cases that should not, together with the desired match to get. Btw, https://regex101.com/r/mZ3mZ6/5 solves it.